# HTTP request without request in Elm 0.18

Tags: elm

I want to do something very un-functional and make an HTTP request in elm without processing any kind of response.  Basically something like this:

```
testView : Html Msg
testView =
  div [] [
    button [onClick TestAction] [text "Test Action"]
  ]
```

---

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
      ...
        TestAction ->
          ( model, testActionCmd )
      ...
```

---

```
import Http
import HttpBuilder exposing (..)
...
testActionCmd : Cmd Msg
testActionCmd =
  ( "http://localhost:4000/fakeurl" )
    |> get  -- this is a side effect; unrelated to the Msg below
  Cmd.none  -- this is what I want to return
```

Is there a way to do something like this in Elm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, no, you won't be able to do that (not without writing your own effect manager or using ports).

The "problem" is that the `Http` module allows you to create a `Task` which you then need to convert into a `Cmd` to perform the task. But to go from a `Task` to a `Cmd` you need to provide a `Msg`. See http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Task

So what you'll need to do is create one of those *Noop* messages.